# What's the difference between poweroff.target, halt.target, reboot.target, shutdown.target and a bunch of others?

Tags: systemd

Systemd defines a bunch of special targets that all relate to shutting down a system, like the ones listed in the title of this post. There seem to be more.

`man systemd.special` gives definitions for them, but does not attempt to differentiate between them.

Just under which circumstances am I supposed to use which of those targets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `shutdown.target` can't be called explicitly, it contains the line `RefuseManualStart=yes`. It is the common part of the other ones, responsible for stopping processes and so on.

`reboot.target` means after shutdown, reboot the system.

`poweroff.target` means after shutdown, power off the system.

`halt.target` means after shutdown, don't do anything (no reboot, no poweroff). The system will just wait in a shutdown state.